# How to encode IDs in a more efficient way - using cryptography library

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I'm trying to anonymize the IDs from a dataset and want to be able to decode back when the data is done using by other people. I found this library online - cryptography.fernet
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/

However, I'm not sure how to change the length of the encryption? It seems very long (128-bit?) and I'm hoping to make it shorter.

It doesn't recognize the same message and encrypt differently. This might cause discrepancies for further analysis.
This is my code:

```py
import cryptography
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = Fernet.generate_key()
w = Fernet(key)
token = w.encrypt(b"my deep dark secret")
w.encrypt(b"my deep dark secret")
```

As you can see I used the same code but have different encryptions

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXHLy.png]

Please let me know if you know how to resolve this, or if anyone has better idea how to encode the identification (or any IDs) and be able to decode back eventually. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "This might cause discrepancies for further analysis" - this is specifically done to make any analysis difficult. The same data may be encrypted to many ciphertexts, but all of them will be decrypted to the same plaintext.